# PFQuery returns Empty Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Soo i have been adding information to parse server, the problem is i can't seem to get the Strings i need via PFQuery.

If I print the objects, it returns an empty Array. Also (fahrtenRequests.count = 0). It has been suggested that this is because that PFQuery can't read my data or my data is not in the right format.

Im completely lost here, it seems everything should work perfectly fine but doesnt

THANKS for your help in advance :) :)

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class HistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var zeit: Array = [String]()
var kosten:Array = [String]()
var kilometer: Array = [String]()
var datum: Array = [String]()


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.tableView.delegate = self

tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CellHistoryViewControllerTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellHistory")


let query = PFQuery(className: "GemachteFahrten")

query.whereKey("gefahreneZeit", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)

query.whereKey("kosten", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)

query.whereKey("createdAt", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)

query.whereKey("gefahreneKilometer", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)


query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

    if error != nil {

        print("error finding user data")


    } else {

        print("check2")

        print(objects!)

        if let fahrtenRequests = objects {


            print(fahrtenRequests.count)
```

Thanks again for any help :)

Comment: I think you cannot fire a query for user's object id with "CreatedAt". I mean this seems not valid: query.whereKey("createdAt", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)

Comment: @Satish Mavani You are right thanks :) its of type Date, but the rest of them should all be strings

Comment: is your issue fixed now?

Comment: @Satish Mavani Unfortunately not, still trying to solve why the other string aren't added to the array, because both should be of type string and it did work in similar previous apps :/ Since im making a taxi app which saves data to parse im also trying to achieve a historyView where all the previously made trips are shown in a tableView :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not how PFQuery works. The object after `equalTo:` must be the same type as the object under the `key:@"..."` in your Parse dashboard.

For example in your case, if you want to retrieve all the trips that one user made, you need to save the user as a pointer to the User class first:(In your parse dashboard, select Edit->Add a Column, then choose Pointer as the type, User as the target class)

```
let trip = PFObject(className:"GemachteFahrten");
//save the user who made this trip
trip["user"] = PFUser.current()
//save other things like costs, distance...etc
trip["kosten"] = ...
trip["gefahreneKilometer"] = ...
trip.saveInBackground()
```

Then, we want to get all the trips that belong to the current user:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "GemachteFahrten")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current())
//then execute the query
```

Please see the Parse documentation http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#queries

Comment: Thanks for the help... unfortunately im not looking for specific trip, cost etc because I dont know in advance what exact value im looking for, i just now its of type string(at least i saved it like this). I tried lots of combinations from the Parse documentation, but till now none work :/

Comment: Also isn’t this what if done ? The Object after equalTo: has the same type as the object under the key““ they are strings, which i want to add to array of strings. I just thought i d have to set the equalTo: to the objectId, which then takes the correct value „cost“ for that whole Trip

Comment: @StefanoChiabotti Hi, are you trying to retrieve all the trips? Coz I'm still a little confused about what you are trying to achieve :/

Comment: @StefanoChiabotti Oh I see, are you trying to get the value for key...? For example the cost for a trip?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response.. im making a taxi app which saves the data on parse after a trip and what im trying to achieve is a historyView where all the previously made trips are. Yes thats it (i guess). I thought id have to define the y-Axis (in this case the equalTo: (objectId)) and the x-Axis(In this case whereKey:"") at least i imagined it like this in my head :P maybe im completely wrong

Comment: @StefanoChiabotti So you wanna get all the trips made by one user? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, Correct :)

Comment: @StefanoChiabotti Please see my edited answer above :)

Comment: YEEAAAAAA!!! Thank you sooo much Gellert !! finally got it to work :D :D You made my day!! and saved my last three!! Thanks again and have a wonderful day!! :)

Comment: @StefanoChiabotti You're welcome. I'm glad it worked for you:)

Answer (score 0):

How can you compare all the columns values with object id of user?

Comparison will result to null, try with the appropriate values.
Also you should not query on `createdAt` parameter, its type of `Date`.
Check for appropriate data types as well.

Comment: Im comparing so it will take the right String out of "kosten"  or "gefahreneZeit" which should be equal to the objectId. Or am I doing this wrong ? I tried this as suggested: query.whereKey("gefahreneKilometer", equalTo: "objectId") but that won't work